# reading the json from a file

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, python-3.x

i have the huge excel  after forming the dictionary objects i just wrote the json objects into file and i want read the json objects from the file
and these objects contains types like datetime.datetime,datetime.date
after writing into the the objects are looking like below

```
"hour_hour": [
    {
      "$date": 1500249600000
    },
    {
      "$date": 1500253200000
    },
    ...
    {
      "$date": 1500321600000
    },
    {
      "$date": 1500325200000
    },
    {
      "$date": 1500328800000
    },
    {
      "$date": 1500332400000
    }
  ]
```

but in the ide it is showing as

```
'hour_hour': 
[datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 17, 0, 0,
tzinfo=bson.tz_util.FixedOffset object at 0x02F2A810>)]
```

i just want to decode it as normal date types
i used json loads

```
class MyEncoder1(json.JSONEncoder):

    def default(self, obj):
        if isinstance(obj,datetime.date):
            date_str = datetime.datetime.strftime(obj,"%Y-%m-%d")
            obj= datetime.datetime.strptime(date_str,"%Y-%m-%d")


for obj in loads(file.read(),cls=MyEncoder1):

    data.append(obj)
```

but it is showing as error
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
can anyone help me

Comment: Please provide a reproducible code example raising your issue.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by huge excel.  Be careful if you are exporting data from excel.  A CSV export from Excel tries to be helpful in ways prevents proper importing elsewhere.  I always use tab delimited as my excel export format.